Error when manually migrating Azure classic cloud service to Extended support cloud service
I am migrating a classic cloud service that contains evo html to pdf generator.  I have created a new extended support cloud service and deploying the associated files.  However, I am receiving the following error when attempting to access the cloud service via the application.

Could not get the error message from server: The connection was closed
by server before the entire data has been read Description: An
unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details:
System.Exception: Could not get the error message from server: The
connection was closed by server before the entire data has been read
Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:
[Exception: Could not get the error message from server: The
connection was closed by server before the entire data has been read]
ac.aa() +2496
EvoPdf.HtmlToPdfClient.HtmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(String html,
String baseUrl) +126    Website.pdf_generation.Page_Load(Object
sender, EventArgs e) +866
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
EventArgs e) +52    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +97
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +61
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+693

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.


Could not get the error message from server: The connection was closed by server before the entire data has been read] ac.aa() +2496

Connection to the Evo PDF server was closed prematurely, which could indicate network issues, timeout settings, or server configuration problems.
Default.aspx:
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <main>
        <section class="row" aria-labelledby="aspnetTitle">
            <h1 id="aspnetTitle">ASP.NET</h1>
            <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </section>

        <div class="row">
            <section class="col-md-4" aria-labelledby="gettingStartedTitle">
                <h2 id="gettingStartedTitle">Getting started</h2>
                <p>
                    ASP.NET Web Forms lets you build dynamic websites using a familiar drag-and-drop, event-driven model.
                    A design surface and hundreds of controls and components let you rapidly build sophisticated, powerful UI-driven sites with data access.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301948">Learn more &raquo;</a>
                </p>
            </section>
            <section class="col-md-4" aria-labelledby="librariesTitle">
                <h2 id="librariesTitle">Get more libraries</h2>
                <p>
                    NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301949">Learn more &raquo;</a>
                </p>
            </section>
            <section class="col-md-4" aria-labelledby="hostingTitle">
                <h2 id="hostingTitle">Web Hosting</h2>
                <p>
                    You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301950">Learn more &raquo;</a>
                </p>
            </section>
        </div>

        <!-- New Section for PDF Conversion -->
        <section class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>PDF Conversion Test</h2>
                <asp:Button ID="btnConvertToPdf" runat="server" Text="Convert to PDF" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnConvertToPdf_Click" />
                <br /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="text-danger"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

</asp:Content>

Make clear that theEvoPdf server is correctly configured, Especially the server address and port if it’s running on a remote server. Replace "localhost" and 0 with the actual server address and port.
Default.aspx.cs:
using System;
using EvoPdf.HtmlToPdfClient;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnConvertToPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Initialize the HTML to PDF converter
                var htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter("localhost", 0); // Replace with your EvoPdf server address and port

                // HTML content to convert (same as the content in the ASP.NET page)
                string htmlContent = @"<html>
                                        <body>
                                            <h1>Test PDF</h1>
                                            <p>This is a test conversion of HTML to PDF using EvoPdf.</p>
                                            <p><a href='http://www.asp.net' class='btn btn-primary btn-md'>Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
                                        </body>
                                      </html>";
                string baseUrl = string.Empty;

                // Convert the HTML string to PDF
                byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlContent, baseUrl);

                // Save PDF to disk (or perform further operations)
                string pdfFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/GeneratedPdf.pdf");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, pdfBuffer);

                lblResult.Text = "PDF generated successfully. You can find the file at " + pdfFilePath;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Display the error message
                lblResult.Text = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
            }
        }
    }
}


Default.aspx.cs file is to handle the PDF conversion when the button is clicked.


Result:


